# How to have 2 units add/subtract a value from 0-15 from numbers to produce a specific result

Tags: linear-algebra

Not a mathamatician here, so i apologize if this is obvious or dumb.

Imagine two units that can either subtract or add any number from 1-15 from a given number.

The units must always add or subtract the same numbers, they cannot change.

If a unit subtracts say 7, from the numbers 5, we just get 0, we dont deal with negative numbers. Also if a unit adds say 7 to 14, we just get 15, as we cant go higher than 15.

A number will pass through the 1st unit, and the result of that will pass through the second unit.

What numbers do these units need to add/subtract such that when given the numbers from 0-9, they produce 0 on the numbers 1 and 4, but a value greater than 0, on the numbers 0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

Is this even possible? If so how, and is there a general rule that i can apply to solve this problem on different versions.

Please let me know if i'm not being clear.

// Example 1

The first unit adds 5, while the second unit subtracts 8. We pass the number 1 to the first unit.

1 -> 6 -> 0 (not -2, because we cant go below 0)

// Example 2

The first unit subtract 3, while the second unit adds 10. We pass the number 15.

15 -> 12 -> 15 (not 22, because we cant go above 15)

// Example 3

The first unit adds 5, the second units subtracts 7. We pass the number 9

9 -> 14 -> 7

Comment: it helps if you show an example

Comment: The question is unclear as it is written. What is a "unit"? Can you give an example? What does it mean for a number to "pass through" a unit? First you say a unit must add or subtract $15$. Then later you ask what numbers the units need to add/subtract, implying that they can add or subtract things other than $15$.

Comment: I see it was unclear, i apologize, and have updated with examples.

Comment: @wgrenard It seems that a "unit" is a "processing unit", which is to say a function.

Comment: @Cortex Here is a little demo for you. The values $a$ and $b$ are the amounts added by the units. (Choose negative numbers for subtraction.) Play around with this and you will get an intuition for why the problem is impossible. In particular, observe that the successive outputs are never decreasing; each one is either the same or one greater than the previous. So if you have $0$ on an input of $1$ and $4$, you must have $0$ on the ones in between as well. [https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mzyzbqru5h](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mzyzbqru5h)

Comment: Great visual @Théophile, thank you for taking the time!

Comment: Also answered my question of wether this was possible with 3 units :P Ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. We have two units and, as you define them, they are machines that can add or subtract a number from a given number.

Let $n$ be given and define a unit's action on $n$ to be $u(n)=n+c$ where $c$ can be plus or minus. Let units $u_1$ and $u_2$ with actions $u_1(n)=n+c_1$ and $u_2(n)=n+c_2$, respectively, be given.

If we run unit one followed by unit two on a number, this is equivalent to $u_2(u_1(n))=u_2(n+c_1)=(n+c_1)+c_2=n+(c_1+c_2)$. Therefore, the combined action is equivalent to a single unit whose value for $c$ can go from $-30$ to $30$.

For this to transform $1$ and $4$ to $0$ requires that $c\le -4$. But this will map $0, 2$ and $3$ to $0$ as well.

Therefore, it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  If you supply $a$ and $b$ with $a \lt b$, the result of $a$ must be less than or equal to the result of $b$, but the result of $4$ is less than the result of $3$.

Comment: I dont understand Ross, can you elaborate? _... the result of 4 is less than the result of 3_ What does this mean? And supply a and b? Do you mean the values that the units add/subtract?

Comment: No, $a$ and $b$ are two input numbers, like $3$ and $4$.  You said that if $3$ is put in the result is greater than $0$, but if $4$ is put in the result is $0$.  Neither of your machines can reverse the order of its inputs.  It can collapse different ones to the same value, but cannot reverse them.