# Combining units to create a desired result based on input.

Tags: linear-algebra

*This is somewhat related to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3311915/how-to-have-2-units-add-subtract-a-value-from-0-15-from-numbers-to-produce-a-spe), however this puzzle actually allows for solutions*

Im not sure if this question belongs on stack overflow or math, but my intuition is its better suited here.

Im attempting to create an algorithm / function, that will allow me to solve a puzzle, but I am simply unable to. The puzzle is as stated.

1. Let a **unit** be a function that accepts a integer **i** between 0 and 15.
2. A unit can add or subtract any number in the range 0 - 15 to/from i.
3. Additionally, instead of adding or subtracting a number to/from i, a unit can also contain a number from 0-15 and subtract i from that.
4. A unit can only perform 2 operations on a number, and the operation 
   producing the largrest value will be the output of the unit.
5. Values only go from 0 - 15, so 9 - 15 = 0 and 13 + 5 = 15.
6. We may combine units together to produce a more complex result.
7. The first unit may only accept numbers ranging from 0 - 9.

In my examples I will string together 3 units.

For example, a problem could be:

> For values 1 and 4, let the output be 0, for all others eg. 0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, the output must be greater than 0.

A solution here might be:

1. U1 = max(5 - input, input)
2. U2 = max(14 - input, input)
3. U3 = max(10 - input, input - 10)

**Note that U2's input, is the output of U1**

Another example might be:

> For values 4, 5, 6 and 8 the output must be 3 or greater, for all others eg. 0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 9, the output must be less than 3.

A solution here might be:

1. U1 = max(4 - input, input - 4)
2. U2 = max(2, input)
3. U3 = max(1 - input, input - 6)

Given an example as the two stated above, is there a general algorithm / forumla I can use to find my desired output?

Additionally, is it possible to solve the problems above using only 2 units?

Please do let me know if I need to elaborate on something, and know that your help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: You should link to [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3311915/how-to-have-2-units-add-subtract-a-value-from-0-15-from-numbers-to-produce-a-spe) and note the difference so people will not have to figure it out.  -1

Comment: I have updated my post, and apologize if it was an inconvenience for you.